# Why is my table not border spacing properly?

Tags: html, css

I have tried to make my table look like this:
[image]

Everything looks great so far, however I am having trouble with my border-spacing, there isn't any for some reason, as shown here:

[image]

So far I have border-spacing in my css, however it isn't doing anything and I am not sure as to why that is.

HTML:

```
<section class="s">
    <center>
        <table class="t">
            <caption class="ex2">HTML Table with CSS</caption>
            <tr>
                <td class="r1c1">This</td>
                <td class="r1c2">Little</td>
                <td class="r1c3">Piggy</td>
                <td class="r1c4">Went</td>
                <td class="r1c5">To</td>
                <td class="r1c6">Market</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="r2c1" colspan="2">This</td>
                <td class="r2c2">Little</td>
                <td class="r2c3">Piggy</td>
                <td class="r2c4">Went</td>
                <td class="r2c5">To</td>

            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="r3c1" colspan="2" rowspan="2">This</td>
                <td class="r3c2" rowspan="2">Little</td>
                <td class="r3c3">Piggy</td>
                <td class="r3c5" rowspan="2">To</td>
                <td class="r3c6" rowspan="2">Market</td>
            </tr>

            <tr> 
                <td class="r3c4">Went</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="r4c1">Little</td>
                <td class="r4c2">Piggy</td>
                <td class="r4c4">Went</td>
                <td class="r4c5">To</td>
                <td class="r4c5" colspan="2">Market</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </center>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
table.t
{
    border: 1px solid;
    border-spacing: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}

td.r1c1 { border: 1px solid; background-color: #6DFFA8; }
td.r1c2 { border: 1px solid; background-color: #6DFFCC; }
td.r1c3 { border: 1px solid; background-color: #6DFFFF; }
td.r1c4 { border: 1px solid; background-color: #70E8FF; }
td.r1c5 { border: 1px solid; background-color: #74CEFF; }
td.r1c6 { border: 1px solid; background-color: #78BAFF; }

td.r2c1 { border: 1px solid; background-color: #6DFFA8; }
td.r2c2 { border: 1px solid; background-color: #33FAB4; }
td.r2c3 { border: 1px solid; background-color: #33F9D8; }
td.r2c4 { border: 1px solid; background-color: #34F0F9; }
td.r2c5 { border: 1px solid; background-color: #3CBCF9; }

td.r3c1 { border: 1px solid; background-color: #6DFFA8; }
td.r3c2 { border: 1px solid; background-color: #00F9F9; }
td.r3c3 { border: 1px solid; background-color: #1094FA; }
td.r3c4 { border: 1px solid; background-color: #1A5EFA; }
td.r3c5 { border: 1px solid; background-color: #242AFA; }
td.r3c6 { border: 1px solid; background-color: #511CFA; }

td.r4c1 { border: 1px solid; background-color: #6DFFA8; }
td.r4c2 { border: 1px solid; background-color: #00D67B; }
td.r4c3 { border: 1px solid; background-color: #00CBCB; }
td.r4c4 { border: 1px solid; background-color: #0E7CD1; }
td.r4c5 { border: 1px solid; background-color: #1750D4; }
```

Comment: For me it's working? https://jsfiddle.net/f72mrt4v/
Edit: I'm using Chrome (latest)

Comment: It looks exactly as you intend it to on Firefox 47.0.1 - what browser are you using?

Comment: @Aer0 I have no clue how or why that is, as shown in the picture It isn't showing any spacing for me. :(

Comment: @Rounin I am using the most updated Chrome.

Comment: maybe you have an another css with `border-collapse:collapse;` in the tables.

Comment: ...also `<center>` is deprecated and should no longer be used.

Comment: I also just tried to open the webpage on firefox 47.0.1 and it shows the exact same thing, I will post the full code of the page to see if something I added previously is causing this problem.

Comment: try adding `border-collapse:separate;` in the table

Comment: @blonfu That worked! Thanks! I'm not sure why it shows up correctly in fiddle, but now everything works perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table rule is missing `border-collapse:separate;` for `border-spacing` to work properly

```
table.t
{
    border-collapse:separate;
}
```

Comment: `border-spacing` is a valid CSS property: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-spacing

Comment: All I needed to add was the `border-collapse:seperate;` to fix this issue!

Comment: Glad to help @AsadMahmood

Comment: Nice to see it actually has cross-browser support these days @blonfu I gave up on it yonks ago because it was unreliable, thanks for the update. http://caniuse.com/#search=border-spacing

Comment: You're talking about a long time ago. `border-spacing` support: since IE6+, Firefox 2+, Chrome 1+ etc

Comment: Yup, divs rule. @blonfu